# python pandas, outer product by row, (N, k) dataframe to (N,k,k) Panel

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a few assets

```
rtns = pd.util.testing.makeTimeDataFrame(5000) # 5000 x 4
stds = pd.rolling_std(rtns, 20) # 5000 x 4
corMat = pd.ewmcorr(rtns, com = 50) # 5000 x 4 x 4
```

For whatever reason, I want to calculate std and correlation separately and reconstruct the covariance matrix. I can do this with a loop

```
out = corMat * 0
for (d,v) in stds.iterrows():
    out[d] = np.outer(v,v) * corMat[d]
```

The main worry is that np.outer loses the column names and it might cause mismatch if assets in stds and corMat are ordered differently. And of course, loops are slow.

Is there a pandas/numpy operation to replace this loop (and automatically take care of asset name matching)?

Answer (score 0):

You can preserve the index of `v` with:

```
out[d] = pd.DataFrame(np.outer(v, v), v.index, v.index) * corMat[d]
```